# How to measure the stack size of a process?

Tags: linux

How do I find the stack size of a process ?
/proc/5848/status gives me VmStk but this doesnt change

No matter how much ever while loop and recursion I do in my test program this value hardly changes.

when I looked at /proc/pid/status all of the process has 136k and have no idea where that value comes from.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to get the stack sizes of individual threads of a multi-threaded process?

Answer (score 8):

There really is no such thing as the "stack size of a process" on Linux. Processes have a starting stack, but as you see, they rarely allocate much from the standard stack. Instead, processes just allocate generic memory from the operating system and use it as a stack. So there's no way for the OS to know -- that detail is only visible from inside the process.

A typical, modern OS may have a stack size limit of 8MB imposed by the operating system. Yet processes routinely allocate much larger objects on their stack. That's because the application is using a stack that is purely application-managed and not a stack as far as the OS is concerned.

This is always true for multi-threaded processes. For single-threaded processes, it's possible they are actually just using very, very little stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please provide examples of languages that still use stack for keeping local variables? (instead of emulating stack with heap).

Comment: @VitalyIsaev I don't think that's likely to be a property of a language. For example, C and C++ programs used to just use the stack for everything a few decades ago. It's more likely to be an implementation property based on the size and complexity of the machine. Essentially, programs have "outgrown" using a single stack provided by the process startup mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you just want to get the address map of some process. For process 1234, read sequentially the `/proc/1234/maps` pseudo-file. For your own process, read `/proc/self/maps`

Try

```
 cat /proc/self/maps
```

to get a feeling of it (the above command displays the address map of the `cat` process executing it).

Read [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page for details.

You might also be interested by process limits, e.g. [getrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) and related syscalls.

<sup>I am not sure that stack size has some precise sense, notably for multi-threaded processes.</sup>

Maybe you are interested in [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed segments with `MAP_GROWSDOWN`.

Answer (score 1):

the stksize can be got by pidstat command. install it by `apt install sysstat`

```
 pidstat -p 11577  -l -s
```

[image]